# Calculate row value referring previous rows in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out a way to compare values from different rows in a dataframe to calculate a new column.

I've found these ways:

- Iterate over rows (I'm looking for a vectorized solution):

`for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ....`

- Merge the same dataframe multiple times using a shift over index, something like this:

`d1 = data.shift()
data.merge(d1[["value col"]], how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Is there a way to access to the current dataframe from an apply method:

```
dataframe.apply(myfunction(row),axis=1)

def my_function(row, current_dataframe)
    index = row.name
    row_to_compare = current_dataframe.iloc[index-delta]
    row["new column"] = calc(row["value], row_to_compare["value"])
    return row
```

Passing it as argument doesn't seem to work:

```
data.apply(date_diff,axis=1,args=(data))
or
data.apply(lambda row,df: date_diff(row, df),axis=1,args=(data))
```

Keeps saying:

```
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to calculate?

If it is simple enough you can vectorize completely. Note you can just add it as another column rather than having a separate merge step.

```
df["same"] = df[col] == df[col2].shift()
```

If it is a bit more complex then can you split it into multiple steps like the above? This will still be fast.

If you need multiple columns and rows then you you will have to use apply to process row by row or column by column but this is quite slow. Worst answer is to iterate! You should never need to do this.

Comment: It's basically a derivative term based on different columns, as you point out  it can be done simply using shift() method, but I was wondering if it can be compiled into a function to make the code more readable.

Comment: Of course you can do anything you want in an apply function. However it will be massively slower.